# How to protect against ASP.NET SQL Injections in SQL Azure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I am interested in creating a connection between an ASP.NET website form and a SQL Azure database in the most secure way possible. The form is simply a contact form that needs to INSERT records into a database table. 
From what I have gathered so far, the most secure way to implement this is to create a separate login, and or a separate user in the database, and grant the user INSERT ONLY permissions on the schema in which to table is contained. I currently have an asp.net website and successfully have the application inserting data into the desired table, with the connection parameters for the azure account being those of the principle level login. Wouldnt it make sense to just create a different user/login for the application and save the principle login for SQL Server Management Studio?
I have read that one of the common methods of avoiding SQL Injection threats is to have a stored procedure in the database. However, it seems to me that a smart idea woudl just be to create a limited user. What are some of the most secure approaches developers are taking in the Backend like SQL Azure ( Related to roles, users, and logins) to protect the website from intruders here, and from the app.config string data from being compromised?

Im currently using ASP.NET, SQL Azure, and C#. And I only use one control which is the contact control of an asp.net web form. The control is placed into multiple pages and has c# code behind. Hope this helps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL Injection can be prevented simply by using parameters instead of building SQL statements dynamically. It has nothing to do with user security. In fact, it's extremely simple to prevent.

Comment: The way to avoid SQL injection threats is not to allow SQL injection. Don't concatenate strings to make SQL statements. Job done. Perhaps use an ORM? Entity Framework springs to mind.

Comment: I have read that as well @JohnSaunders, however, wouldnt it make sense to have an application login instead of storing principle level login data in the application config file?

Comment: @user3256123 : you're asking a very different question now. This has not much to do with Sql injection... more to do with best practice with regard to securing a database and limiting damage if compromise occurs.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like the concern regarding injection is remedied through only allowing control values to be passed as parameters in stored procedures. But are there any other concerns having principle login data as the connection parameter other than another login @spender ?

Comment: Connection strings can be encrypted in the config file. Again, this has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (such as Entity Framework or NHibernate) is the standard way to protect against sql-injections: it deals with proper parameter encoding.

Another way is using [sql command parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) if you prefer avoiding ORM and using simple ADO.net access: this will encode insertions too.

Limiting user permissions can be useful generally, but **not sufficient** to protect from injections (as you can still inject a string to insert rubbish data).

E.g. you build your query this way:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.USERS(Name) values ('" + userNameFromForm + "')";
```

I can attack this by sending the following username: `John') insert into dbo.USERS(Name) values ('rubbish` which would result in the following query executed:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.USERS(Name) values ('John') insert into dbo.USERS(Name) values ('rubbish')
```

Comment: thank you. You bring up a good point. Passing parameters is necessary to prevent sql injection, but not sufficient to prevent compromise. Can you refer me to a book that details other threats?@isantipov

Comment: @ExcelApplications , I don't have a book on sql security but here is a nice series on top 10 web security issues to start with http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html